# Site pages show the page title under navigation bar

Tags: menus, navigation

On all my site pages it displays the page they are already on under the navigation bar e.g 'Home' as in the photo. How can I not show this?
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your theme (or child theme) is likely using `page.php` as the default page template.  This file likely contains a call to the WP function `the_title()` which is generating the visible page title.

Multiple options to modify this.  Assuming you are using a theme which will have updates available, your changes should be made using the Child Theme approach in WordPress.  https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes.   This will ensure your changes survive an update to the parent theme.

Assuming you never want the page title to show, simply removing the call to `the_title()` and any associated markup (heading tags, etc) will eliminate this.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. It's a little technical for me so I shall need to look into exactly how and where to remove, the_title.